# Node.js with Express: Change response data for certain path

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sapui5

I've read many guides and did not find what I need, so maybe you can help me! :)

I created an UI5 Application and I am using Node.js with Express on the server-side. I retrieve data from a SQL database and display it in UI5. For this, I do the following on the server side:

```
request.query(statement, function(err, recordset) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("SQL error: " + err);
        }
        app.use('/Scanners', function(req, res) {
            res.send(recordset);
        });
```

On the client side, the value returned by this is retrieved:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/Scanners"
    }).done(function(data, status, jqxhr) {
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        var modelData = 
 "{ \"Number\": " + (totalScanners-(+data[0].Number))+ "}";
        oModel.setData(JSON.parse(modelData));
        var oTextView = sap.ui.getCore().byId("tvscanner");
        oTextView.setModel(oModel);
```

Now, there are some text fields, from which I read values and after that I perfom an UPDATE operation on the database. When that is done, I'd like to repeat the first operation as shown above, but the data on path `/Scanners` does not change. How can I get this work to work?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably move the query inside the request callback, like this:

```
app.use('/Scanners', function(req, res) {
    request.query(statement, function(err, recordset) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("SQL error: " + err);
            res.send(JSON.stringify({error: "SQL ERROR: " + err}));
        } else {
            res.send(recordset);
        }
    }
});
```

You can replace the line in which you send the error with something else, an empty response for instance. Just remember to send back something or the client will wait for a long time until the request is canceled for a timeout error.